# setting a list result returned from controller to jquery variable

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

i have a returnig list result from controller to View

```
@model List<CartItemDetailDto>
```

is it possible to have this result list set to a jquery variable

```
 <script>
    var modelList =@(Model);
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use that. Just convert in to Json String like below:

`var json = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(@Model));`

now you can use your model data in Jquery.

Comment: It will convert model into json object and JSON.srtingify will convert that object into json string. I already used same approach and it's working well for me.

Comment: oh Fine will make changes according to your comment.